# Sync a custom chrome extension across all computers that chrome user is longed in?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, file-synchronization

Anyone know of a chrome extension that syncs DATA of each individual chrome extension? For example, it will sync a list of rules you created for a custom extension across all current chrome user account login?

Not the extension which is already automatically done by default from google but the settings and data that you assigned to each extension.

For each new computer all info entered into that extension I need to set up on the other extension. the time it takes to set it up add could one drag and drop the folders of the extension used.

I think I tried that before even the data from the chrome's user profile but not sure it worked like if install the same extension on both computers and drag the changed data inside that extension folder.
Do you think that's a way to do it cause I could kind of rig up a cloud sync way to go about it, for example, it updates the folder I assume I run it problems where cannot edit the file while its open maybe a restart of the browser would do it.

I learned that you could upload the extension to website and not have it viewed by the public so one method since the extension is not my code is to go about this method then add to the extension that is on GitHub that chrome extension storage from local to sync. https://github.com/maripo/CustomFilter

I hope to figure out how to add this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

to current extension since it's on GitHub
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

chrome extension database saves new info into the user folder that looks like this \Chrome\User Data\Profile 4\databases\chrome-extension_elnfhb  if you open the file its 010100

Comment: if the dev did not include it it in the code before being published on web store then i would guess i need to ask for permission not sure if sideloaded extension if sideloaded on both computers will sync if the new extension that i forked from github and add the following to have it sync https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Forgot to include the extension i working with is called Custom Filter
https://github.com/maripo/CustomFilter

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide price and platform needs, and I don't know what kind of extension you use. But if you're working on Windows computers and your extension saves settings locally (if you don't need to login) you can download **Google Chrome Portable** at

https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Install it to a folder, compress to make it a single file and secure. After playing with Chrome's settings or extensions do the compressing again and rename the file compressed. You don't need to delete any folder like the ones created AppData.

It seems there isn't any sycronization alternative yet.

Comment: well i found some info outt
this is the extension https://github.com/maripo/CustomFilter i gotta figure out way to ad this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage